# Discrete optimisation of a gym workout routine

Tags: optimization, operations-research

I am working on the following problem, which I would like to solve using an elegant optimisation method (both because the answer is genuinely useful to me, and because I am interested in the maths of it).

So, when I go to the gym to lift weights, there are 10 exercises I do. On each gym session, I do each exercise, one after the other (for example "chest press", "bicep curl", "squat"). Each exercise works a different groups of muscles, and there are 5 different muscles (for example "pecs", "bicep", "legs"). Some exercises work multiple groups, and some groups are worked by multiple different exercises. The problem I want to solve is that of choosing the optimum order to perform these tasks in.

The reason this is an important decision is because if I perform two exercises, which work the same muscles, one after the other, then it causes fatigue and makes the second exercise ineffective. So, I need to maximise the time between exercising each muscle. My proposed cost function is therefore the sum over all muscles, of the average time between each exercise which worked that muscle.

What I would like to know, is how to solve this kind of problem. I am familiar with convex optimisation using gradient descent, but there is not differentiable function here, and is more a discrete optimisation problem which I know nothing about. Any pointers in the right direction? Thanks!

(p.s. there are probably simple solutions to this, e.g. just trying out every combination one and evaluating it, but I'm interested in the proper mathematical solution to this kind of optimisation problem).

Comment: I'd rather consult a personal trainer then use optimization algorithm for this...

Comment: I know, but I just thought this would be a good example for me to learn about optimisation. Maybe I should have just left out the gym references and described it in generic terms...

Comment: Do you have any application to statistics or machine learning?

Comment: This is a scheduling problem, look through https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=scheduling  for ideas. Maybe try linear programming